# Using the same color (changeable at runtime) for each vertex

Tags: opengl, webgl

I have just completed this tutorial here: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134

I am now trying to make a simple modification. I don't want each vertex to have a unique color, I want all vertices to use the same color which I can change dynamically.

Here is the relevant code from the tutorial.

```
var squareVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexColorBuffer);
colors = []
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    colors = colors.concat([0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]);
}
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
squareVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
squareVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 4;
```

I have tried the following modification and many other variants.

```
squareVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexColorBuffer);
colors = [0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
squareVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
squareVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 1;
```

The error I am getting is

```
.WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

This error makes perfect sense. I imagine the rendered thinks that there is a unique color for each vertex and so for the nth vertex its looking for the nth color.

The problem is I eventually wish to draw 1 million points and each point is always going to be the same color. So I really don't want to create 4 million floats when all I need is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, its as simple as.

shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
gl.uniform4fv(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

Comment: Remember to be consistent, `"aVertexColor"` should be just `"uColor"`.